# Move a point in 3D space a given distance and angle

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, angle

so I'm fairly new to maths and need to know how to move a given 3D point in space, a certian distance and a certian angle and get the new position, that angle being in radians and being an x angle and y angle (like a camera pointing towards somewhere).
Thanks!

Comment: You need more than an angle and distance to get a new point.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! However I am certain this question has been asked many times. Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.

Comment: but its easy to do in 2D using basic trig, so how would I then add the third dimension z into that?